# How to use Next with Convex?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, convex

**What are the main functionalities of the Convex platform?
Do I need a special kind of account or subscription to use Convex?**

Answer (score 0):

these answers can be found on the Convex website: https://convex.dev and Convex docs: https://docs.convex.dev.

Specifically:

#### Q: What are the main functionalities of the Convex platform?

A: Functions, Database, File Storage, Authentication, Scheduling, Full Text Search, Vector Search

#### Q: Do I need a special kind of account or subscription to use Convex?

A: You need a Convex account to use the Cloud product, and there's a generous free tier.

#### Q: How do I use Convex with Next.js?

Check out the Next.js docs: https://docs.convex.dev/client/react/nextjs/